# Where to find in depth accessibility API documentation

Tags: mac, accessibility

I want to write an application that leverages the Apple accessibility APIs to embellish texts on the screen.

My goal is to overlay additional information on text that the user is reading/typing.

Apple provides APIs that are poorly documented. I can't find good information or example git projects to learn from.

The documentation I am basing from is mainly found here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices?language=objc

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html

My end goal is to be able to embellish texts with an underline or some other visual effect (shadow, box, etc.). When the user has hovered over those elements the helper application should present an additional overlay (hovering window) which I can manage (displaying some information).

Some example applications using the Accessibility APIs are:

Skitch (for screen capture)
Better snap tool (for window management)
Grammarly (for fixing grammatical errors)

The best example of what I need to achieve is Grammarly which can modify texts and apply some UI effects to what is currently being typed.

Answer (score 2):

These might be what you are looking for:

- https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/resources
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accessibility
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/accessibility_for_appkit
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibilityprotocol

Comment: these describe how to make your app accessible. I'm looking for how to I can write an app which controls others which are themselves accessbile

Comment: for instance how grammerly can fix mistakes in any text editing application